# Merge jquery resizable with jquery-ui-resizable

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

Today I came across the tag [jquery-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-resizable), Which doesn't even have a tag wiki. The question was clearly about [jquery-ui-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-resizable) and I [can't find any other such plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20resizable&oq=jquery%20resizable&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.4561j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

There are currently 40 questions tagged [jquery-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-resizable).

- Some clearly mention [jquery-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) in the title itself
- Some mention jquery ui in the description
- Some are tagged with both jquery-ui-resizable as well.
- Rest of the very few are just asking how to resize an element, it isn't related to a particular plugin, and i don't see any other such function or plugin other than jquery-ui-resizable.

I tried to suggest it as a synonym but failed since i don't have 5 score on it. If i retag every question related to jquery ui with [jquery-ui-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-resizable), will it get automatically deleted..? Or am I wrong ..? (*I better ask this for the reason mentioned earlier*) If so, can someone point to the correct source and update the wiki..?